# `binding.pry` causing `ArgumentError: non-absolute home`

Tags: ruby, pry

Under what condition might [pry](https://github.com/pry/pry) fail with this error?

```
ArgumentError: non-absolute home
```

**code at failure point:**

```
puts "ENV['HOME']: #{ENV['HOME']}"
binding.pry
```

**stack trace:**

```
ENV['HOME']: localhost:3000                                                     
rake aborted!                                                                   
ArgumentError: non-absolute home                                                
/Users/bart_simpson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@kewl_project/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/pry_class.rb:105:in `expand_path'
/Users/bart_simpson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@kewl_project/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/pry_class.rb:105:in `real_path_to'
/Users/bart_simpson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@kewl_project/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/pry_class.rb:100:in `block in rc_files_to_load'
/Users/bart_simpson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@kewl_project/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/pry_class.rb:100:in `map'
/Users/bart_simpson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@kewl_project/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/pry_class.rb:100:in `rc_files_to_load'
/Users/bart_simpson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@kewl_project/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/pry_class.rb:88:in `load_rc_files'
/Users/bart_simpson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@kewl_project/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/pry_class.rb:148:in `initial_session_setup'
/Users/bart_simpson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@kewl_project/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/pry_class.rb:184:in `start'
/Users/bart_simpson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@kewl_project/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/core_extensions.rb:43:in `pry'
/Users/bart_simpson/Projects/kewl_project/kewl_project/lib/tasks/kewl_project_tasks_helper.rb:104:in `block in import_energy_storage_facilities_from_state_task2'
/Users/bart_simpson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/csv.rb:1764:in `each' 
/Users/bart_simpson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/csv.rb:1142:in `block in foreach'
/Users/bart_simpson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/csv.rb:1289:in `open' 
/Users/bart_simpson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/csv.rb:1141:in `foreach'
/Users/bart_simpson/Projects/kewl_project/kewl_project/lib/tasks/kewl_project_tasks_helper.rb:100:in `import_energy_storage_facilities_from_state_task2'
/Users/bart_simpson/Projects/kewl_project/kewl_project/lib/tasks/kewl_project_tasks_helper.rb:69:in `import_energy_storage_facilities_via_state_task'
/Users/bart_simpson/Projects/kewl_project/kewl_project/lib/tasks/kewl_project.rake:215:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
/Users/bart_simpson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@kewl_project/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:273:in `block in execute'
/Users/bart_simpson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@kewl_project/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:273:in `each'
/Users/bart_simpson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@kewl_project/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:273:in `execute'
/Users/bart_simpson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@kewl_project/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:214:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/bart_simpson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/monitor.rb:226:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/bart_simpson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@kewl_project/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:194:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/bart_simpson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@kewl_project/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:183:in `invoke'
/Users/bart_simpson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@kewl_project/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `invoke_task'
/Users/bart_simpson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@kewl_project/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/bart_simpson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@kewl_project/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `each'
/Users/bart_simpson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@kewl_project/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `block in top_level'
/Users/bart_simpson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@kewl_project/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:125:in `run_with_threads'
/Users/bart_simpson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@kewl_project/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in `top_level'
/Users/bart_simpson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@kewl_project/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:83:in `block in run'
/Users/bart_simpson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@kewl_project/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/bart_simpson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@kewl_project/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:80:in `run'
/Users/bart_simpson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@kewl_project/gems/rake-12.3.2/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/bart_simpson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@kewl_project/bin/rake:23:in `load'     
/Users/bart_simpson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@kewl_project/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'   
/Users/bart_simpson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@kewl_project/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `eval'
/Users/bart_simpson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@kewl_project/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => kewl_project:import_energy_storage_facilities
```

---

## UPDATE

I found that if I issue `binding.pry` immediately after `require 'pry'` at the top of the module (i.e. not within a method but outside any method scope), then it works and `ENV['HOME']` is what we would expect:

```
/Users/bart_simpson
```

So now the question is: where does `ENV['HOME']` get changed to `localhost:3000`??

Comment: I'm not familiar with this error but found a couple things on google: [fog](https://github.com/fog/fog/issues/397), [net::ssh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10391298/error-non-absolute-home-via-netssh).  Would suggest printing contents of `ENV['HOME']` or `echo $HOME`.

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace?

Comment: https://github.com/pry/pry/issues/477

Comment: Thanks, I saw *fog*, *net:ssh*, *pry/issues/477*. `ENV['HOME']` is `localhost:3000`. I added the stack trace.

Comment: Updated question with additional info.

Comment: Figured out the problem - added answer. Let me know if I should delete this question.

Answer (score 0):

`ENV['HOME']` was overridden.

Someone added `ENV['HOME']='localhost:3000'` to our app environment variables. Bad!

Sorry to have wasted everyone's time!